# C# Having panels show with push of button, toggle between them not working

Tags: forms, loading, buttonclick

So I'm trying to load forms inside of my panel with the click of a button. But the problem I'm having is toggling between them. I can click one and it shows, but clicking the other one won't load anything. What am I doing wrong? I want to be able to just click a button (i have 5 different ones) and have it load the forms inside of the panel(replacing the old one I loaded). I can't seem to find an answer that helps me. Can someone help me or show me in the right direction?

My main form has the buttons on the left side and I have my container (panel from the toolbox) to the right which I'm trying to load the forms inside.

Below I included 2 sample buttons I have. All the other ones have the same code inside them. No other codes anywhere else for this function.

I'm new to c#, this may be the reason I'm struggling with such a simple task probably.

```
private void btn1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            test1 test1 = new test1();
            test1.TopLevel = false;
            test1.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
            this.pContainer.Controls.Add(test1);
            test1.Show(); 

        }

        private void btn2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            test2 test2 = new test2();
            test2.TopLevel = false;
            test2.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
            this.pContainer.Controls.Add(test2);
            test2.Show();
        }
```